# Can't get Ajax to work withe PHP the way I want to

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a login and registration form on the same page, which I hide with jQuery so only one form is active at a time. When I have the registration form active, fill out the email field with an email that don't match my PHP if-statement and press submit then the page refreshes and activates the login form.

What I want the page to do is run the PHP script, when the PHP if-statement fails it is gonna prevent the refresh of the page and then print the message located in the PHP else-statement.

The code looks like this:

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $request = $_POST['request'];

    $email = $DBcon->real_escape_string($email);
    $password = $DBcon->real_escape_string($password);

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $check_email = $DBcon->query("SELECT email FROM members WHERE email='$email'");
    $count = $check_email->num_rows;

    if ($count==0) {
        if (preg_match('/^[a-z]{6}+[0-9]{2}+@student.westerdals.no+$/i', $email)) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO members(email, password) VALUES('$email', '$hashed_password')";
            $result = $DBcon->query($query);
            header("Location: home.php");
            die();
        } else {
            echo "You must provide a valid student email!";
        }
    } else{
        echo "Email already taken!";
    }
}
$DBcon->close();
```

jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

var request = $(this).serialize();
$("#registerform").on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

     $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'registration.php',
     data: request,
     success: function(){
       $(this).submit();
       console.log("test");
     },
     error: function () {
        event.preventDefault();
     alert("fail");
     }
     });

   });
});
```

Comment: Put `var request = $(this).serialize();` into submit function.

Comment: I have tried this, but I get this error: " Undefined index: request in...." referred to my "$request = $_POST['request'];" in my PHP. When I run "print_r($_POST);" the values of request are actually being printed..

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that your code run properly and you receive the data properly through post in javascript then only these changes are to be done.

```
 if ($count==0) {
        if (preg_match('/^[a-z]{6}+[0-9]{2}+@student.westerdals.no+$/i', $email)) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO members(email, password) VALUES('$email', '$hashed_password')";
            $result = $DBcon->query($query);

     if ($result){
         header("Location: home.php");
      }
     else{ 
          die("Some error");
     }
            die();
        } else {
          die("You must provide a valid student email!");
        }
    } else{
        die("Email already taken!");
    }
```

Comment: Now I keep getting " Undefined index: request in...." referred to my "$request = $_POST['request'];" in my PHP. When I run "print_r($_POST);" the values of request are actually being printed..

Comment: Check if you have used the name of the keyword in the form as 'request' . This error shows up only when you don't have a value for $_POST[variable]; So check the variable part. Also check if it is properly passed to php.

Comment: When I changed the object to be serialized from "this" to the actual form id "#registerform" it worked partly, it won't print from the else statement in the PHP("you must provide a valid student email"). But then, on the error part of the Ajax I get the alert to work, but not the prevent default. Any tips for that?

Comment: if that is working fine then go with it. As there is no problem in it.

Or else create a new php page showing error. And then use redirect to display error.

Or simply use show/hide way to display error. Hide the <p>Your error message</p>. Then in ajax if error persist the display it.  

Or simply just print error in html in ajax.